# std::conditional in nested template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to implement a RingBuffer in the style of the STL. This means I'm also implementing an iterator for it that has to work as either const or non-const. This is just the iterator part:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> class RingBuffer {
public:
    class Iterator;
    // actual RingBuffer implementation here
};    

template <typename T, bool is_const=false> 
class RingBuffer<T>::Iterator {
public:
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef typename std::conditional<is_const, const value_type*, value_type*>::type pointer ;
    typedef typename std::conditional<is_const, const value_type&, value_type&>::type reference ;
    typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    // a bunch of functions here
    ...
};
```

GCC 4.8.0 gives errors for every line where I try to access an iterator, saying something like

```
no type named 'type' in 'struct std::conditional<is_const, const int*, int*>'
```

Substituting `int` for the type that `RingBuffer<T>` has been instantiated with. I don't get it. `is_const` has a default value. Why doesn't this work? And why doesn't GCC subsitute in `false` in the error message, like it substituted `int` for `value_type`?

The solution is probably obvious but all the googling in the world didn't get me anywhere. Templates are still kind of confusing to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want `Iterator` to also be templated by `bool is_const`, you have to declare it as such:

```
template <typename T> class RingBuffer {
public:
    template <bool is_const = false>
    class Iterator;
    // actual RingBuffer implementation here
};    


template <typename T>
template <bool is_const> 
class RingBuffer<T>::Iterator {
public:
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef typename std::conditional<is_const, const value_type*, value_type*>::type pointer ;
    typedef typename std::conditional<is_const, const value_type&, value_type&>::type reference ;
    typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    // a bunch of functions here
    ...
};
```

Explanation: `Iterator` is a member of a class template, but in your original code, `Iterator` itself was a non-template class. `RingBuffer` had one template parameter, `T`; `Iterator` was a non-template class; there just wasn't anywhere for `is_const` to appear. It will become clearer if we remove the outer class for a moment:

```
class Foo;

template <bool b = false>
class Foo
{
  // something
};
```

I believe it's obvious the above wouldn't work.

Comment: I can't claim to understand _why_, but that works. Can you explain what I did wrong and what your version does right? Also: I can't seem to use `RingBuffer<T>::Iterator` (without the is_const argument) even though it has a default value. Why is that? Can that be changed so that I only have to specify is_const when I actually want to deviate from the default?

Comment: @sseeland Added explanation. As for why `RingBuffer<T>::Iterator` doesn't work - it has to be `RingBuffer<T>::Iterator<>`. Unlike for function templates, there is no deduction mechanism for class templates, which also means you always have to specify `<>` (even if empty).